Symfony Api Platform - Not filtered duration
I'm currently on a Symfony Api Platform project and i need to know how to filter a duration
There is my object simplified
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Context;
use App\Repository\VideoRepository;

#[ORM\Table(name: 'videos')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: VideoRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection()
    ]
)]
#[ApiFilter(
    filterClass: RangeFilter::class,
    properties: [
        'duration',
    ],
)]
class Video
{

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'ID', type: Types::INTEGER)]
    private string $id;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'DURATION', type: Types::TIME_MUTABLE, nullable: true)]
    #[Context([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'H:i:s'])]
    private ?\DateTime $duration;

    // Other properties ...
    // Getter and Setter ...

}

This is the BDD data for example:
id | duration
1  | 00:05:12
2  | 00:03:00
3  | 00:00:41

Then i try this call: GET {base_url}/videos?duration[gt]=00:03:00
I should have 1 result, but then i try i have the 3 result like the filter don't work
What is missing ? What is wrong ?
Why isn't the time passed understood as time?

What do these columns really contain?

Maybe you need to use DateFilter::class

It does not seem appropriate at all to use  a DateTime to register a duration.
Why not simply use an int (number of seconds).
Then everything would become easy to filter .....

If you have 2 duration "2024-07-14 00:05:10" and "2024-07-15 00:03:10". The later is greater than the first one. You are comparing two dates not two durations ...

For legacy reasons
I need to use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types::TIME_MUTABLE
So I need a DateTime to be able to receive this value
In addition, the data representation must be in H:i:s format.
This includes filters

I've found a roundabout way of getting my way
I copied and pasted the RangeFilter
Then I adapted it to my needs
It's not really a solution, but it suits my use case.
Edit:
My solution is to create a directory in my src
src/Filters/TimeRangeFilter
After that go in my vendor dir to get RangeFilter
Copy this files in your directory
vendor/api-platform/core/src/Doctrine/Orm/Filter/RangeFilter.php
vendor/api-platform/core/src/Doctrine/Common/Filter/RangeFilterTrait.php
vendor/api-platform/core/src/Doctrine/Common/Filter/RangeFilterInterface.php

With this, adapt everything to not have a clone of RangeFilter
In my case, rename everything in "TimeRangeFilter*.php"
In TimeRangeFilterTrait.php
In functions normalizeBetweenValues and normalizeValue
Make it accept the "H:i:s" values
And you should be good
I have adapted the TimeRangeFilter.php / addWhere function but just simple refactoring
And edit the ApiFilter field
#[ApiFilter(
    filterClass: TimeRangeFilter::class,
    properties: [
        'duration',
    ],
)]

I've basically copied paste and adapted RangeFilter

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
